# Algorithm for modified 2D irregular bin packing

Tags: approximation, packing

So usually bin packing algorithms compute the tightest packed solution. I want to calculate the opposite, in my case the solution with the most space between the packed objects is needed. I tried googling for such an algorithm, but I can only find "normal" bin packing solutions.

I need to pack polygons into a given space, the polygons could be approximated with rectangles to make it a bit easier, but in the end I'd prefer to work directly with polygons.
To complicate things further, I also have preloaded objects, which to be honest I have no idea how to handle.

So here are my questions: How do I even start with this project? Is there a term for packing with the most space between objects? Are there any existing projects/ libraries on that topic (preferably C++)?

PS: I looked into libnest2D, but I have a hard time understanding what's happening there. So far I have some code snippets for packing with preloaded objects and for packing with a certain minimum distance between objects, but I couldn't do both at the same time.